# Fitnesse-Fixture for method that return data types like data set

Tags: fitnesse

I am trying to test the .NET class using fitnesse. Is it possible with fitnesse to test a method that returns (not a single value either string or integer) a data set.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. For example, you can return a json object and view the contents of the json object as a return value of a function.

```
|script |className |
| $variable=  |functionName|
```

For a json object returned, you should be able to view its contents assigned to $variable.

The steps associated with other data structures are similar

Answer (score 0):

A dataset return value is automatically handled with an Array fixture:

```
|SomeClass|
|SomeMethodThatReturnsDataSet|
|column1|column2|column3|
|a|b|c|
|d|e|f|
```

See http://fitsharp.github.io/Fit/FixtureWrapper.html for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

You can return [IEnumerable class and check the table](https://github.com/imanushin/NetRunner/wiki/Collection-result).

See whole tutorial there: https://github.com/imanushin/NetRunner/wiki/Net-Runner-tutorial